# CSS .Active background

Tags: css, background

i'm currentley trying to make a website nav bar, when the page is active i want the navbar background to be the same as the body.
However, when i do this the background only wraps around the text rather than the full height of the navbar.

My HTML

```
<div id="navbar">

<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" class="active">    Home</a> </li> 
<li><a href="purchase.html">Purchase</a> </li>
<li><a href="contact.php ">Contact</a> </li>
<li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
 #navbar  ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
background-image:url('Images/black.png');

text-align:center;

height:60px;

}

#navbar ul{

list-style-type:none;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;

}
#navbar ul li{
display:inline;

}
#navbar ul li a{
color:#36b6f4;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:30px; 
margin:30px;

}


#navbar ul li a.active{
height:60px;
background-image:url('Images/background.jpg');


}
```

Comment: what are the dimensions of your images ?

Comment: Its a texture, both are 334x334 px

Comment: You should assign the image in `li`, not in `a.active`

Comment: you mean like #navbar ul li .active{
height:60px;
background-image:url('Images/background.jpg');
i want it on the current page only.

}

Comment: Yes, as `a` normally does not span across full height & width, unless you make it `display: table`

Comment: read my edit, i only want it on the active page.

Answer (score 1):

I have create for you a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RKRHE/1/

I have changed your background images with colors (because I haven't your images).

The problem was `display: inline;`. You can put `float: left;`

You can copy my code from fiddle and change background color with you images.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now my text floats left..:(